# Java Character Encoding Writing to Text File

Tags: java, linux, encoding, utf-8, filewriter

> My Issue is as follows:

Having issue with character encoding when writing to text file. The issue is characters are not showing the intended value. for example I am writing ' '(which is probably a Tab character) and 'Â' is what is displayed in the text file.

> Background information

This data is being stored on a MSQL Database. The Database Collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and the fields are `varchar`. I've come to learn the collation and type determine what character encoding is used on the database side. Values are stored correctly so no issues here.

My Java application runs queries to pull the data from the DB and this too also looks OK. I have debugged the code and seen all the Strings have the correct representation before writing to the file.

Next I write the text to the .TXT file using a `OutputStreamWriter` as follows:

```
public OfferFileBuilder(String clientAppName, boolean isAppend) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String exportFileLocation = getExportedFileLocation();
        File offerFile = new File(getDatedFileName(exportFileLocation+"/"+clientAppName+"_OFFERRECORDS"));
        bufferedWriter  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(offerFile, isAppend), "UTF-8"));
    }
```

Now once I open up the file on the Linux server by running `cat` command on file or open up the file using notepad++ some of the characters are incorrectly displaying.

I've ran the following commands on the server to see its encoding `locale charmap` which prints `UTF-8`, `echo $LANG` which prints `en_US.UTF-8`, and echo $LC_CTYPE` prints nothing.

> Here is what I've attempted so far.
>   I've attempted to change the Character encoding used by the OutputStreamWriter I've tried UTF-8, and CP1252. When switching encoding some characters are fixed when others are then improperly displayed.
>
> My Question is this:
>   Which encoding should my OutputStreamWriter be using?
>   (Bonus Questions) how are we supposed to avoid issues like this from happening. The rule of thumb i was provided was use `UTF-8` and you will never run into problems, but this isn't the case for me right now.

Comment: How about using `UTF-8` encoding with [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) class? It's dedicated for text output streams.

Comment: What is output of `echo $LC_CTYPE`?

Comment: When using Notepad++, verify that the "Encoding" pull-down menu says "UTF-8 without BOM". *(that's what it should on Windows anyway, assuming Linux version is similar)*

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist I havn't tried `PrintWriter` but it inherits from `Writer` which I am using

Comment: @Andreas when i run echo $LC_CTYPE it actually prints nothing.

Comment: Also, sample code buffers the file twice.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos thanks for pointing that out I've tried so many different variations let me update with the correct one

Comment: This code looks good, have you tried running the output through `hd` to identify what is output?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos sorry unfamiliar with acronym `hd`

Comment: `hd` is a hex dump command; it shows the hex values of the characters in the file.

Comment: ok i was able to run the hexdump. Not sure how useful it will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running `file -bi` command on the server revealed that the file was encoded with `ascii` instead of `utf8`. Removing the file completely and rerunning the process fixed this for me.